# How to set default input for input keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have a webpage written in React (but it should not be strictly relevant to that question) that is composed by several inputs, let's call them Name, Surname and Code.

To work quickly, the insertion of the code is done with a Barcode Scanner that works as external keyboard. My idea is that if some field is focused, the keypress is inserted in the focused input but, in case no input is focused, I want to automatically focus and fill the Code input.

Is there a way to that it easily?

Comment: Do you want to manually focus an input imperatively? like using a ref?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputName = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
let inputSurname = document.querySelector('input[name="surname"]');
let inputCode = document.querySelector('input[name="code"]');

let focusedInput = null;

[inputName, inputSurname, inputCode].forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    focusedInput = null;
  });
  input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    focusedInput = input;
  });
});

document.body.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  if (focusedInput == null) {
    inputCode.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Surname</label>
  <input type="text" name="surname" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Code</label>
  <input type="text" name="code" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const surnameInput = document.getElementById('surname-input');
... (= do for all inputs)

let activeInput;

surnameInput.onFocus = () => { activeInput = surnameInput };
...

surnameInput.OnBlur = () => { activeInput = undefined };
...

document.addEventListener('keypress', (ev) => {
    const input = activeInput ?? codeInput;
    input.value += valueOftheKey;
}
```

You'd obviously have to evaluate if the key that was pressed has a value which you can add to the input, but I think this should give you an Idea of what to do. I haven't tried it out though, so it might not completely work.

Also: I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it's an option.

EDIT: Answer by Kostas is better ;) except for the `null`...you should use `undefined`